# Bash how to get date 2017.2.4 but not 2017.02.04

Tags: bash

If I use `date +%Y.%m.%d`, output might be `2017.02.04`. But what I want is `2017.2.4`, how to make it in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-` (hyphen): Will not pad the field

```
date +%Y.%-m.%-d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date +%Y.%m.%d | sed 's/\.0/\./g'
```

Comment: See the answer by franklinsijo. That's better! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a `bash` question, if you're using version 4.2 or higher, you can use the built-in `printf` command instead of forking the `date` binary:

```
printf '%(%Y.%-m.%-d)T\n' -1
```